# Get object with the highest number of related objects

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

Is it possible to get object which has the highest number of related objects?

I want to choose most used plan which is a plan with the maximal number of `UserPlan` objects.

I can get the number but not the instance.

```
number_of_users = Plan.objects.aggregate(max_users=Max('userplan'))['max_users']
```

code:

```
class UserPlan(Model):
   plan = ForeignKey('Plan'..)

class Plan(Model):
   ...

    @staticmethod
    def favorite(self):
        number_of_users = Plan.objects.aggregate(max_users=Max('userplan'))['max_users']
        # ?
```

I could find it using loop but it could be slow.

Answer (score 0):

Since the information is already stored in a column, how about we just sort it?

obj_most_popular = Plan.objects.order_by('userplan').first()

You can read more about it in the docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#order-by